# issue with converting sql to HQL

Tags: grails, groovy, hql, grails-orm

I am trying to change the SQL query below to HQL in my grails-groovy application

```
    top10UserActivityQuery =
"select sum(trans_cnt) as t_cnt, employeeid as username from map2_data "+
"where fdate between (:datefrom) and (:dateto) and res_id=:res_id and location =:location "+
"group by employeeid order by t_cnt desc limit 10;"
der rows = myds.rows(top10UserActivityQuery )
```

How do I use the createcriteria in GORM for this..or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the criteria would be similar to the following:

```
def criteria = DomainClass.createCriteria()
def topTen = criteria.list {
    and {
        between("fdate", dateFrom, dateTo)
        eq("res", resId)
        eq("location", location)
    }
    projections {
        sum("trans_cnt")
        groupProperty("employee")
        property("employee")
    }
}
```

however, i'd suggest using the direct hql this criteria generates.